# Favoured position in nitration of pyrrole

Tags: resonance, heterocyclic-compounds, nitro-compounds

I try to figure out the preferred position of nitration (determine whether compound A or B is the major product) by looking at the resonance structures of the intermediate cation.

[image]

The solution then showed that for compound A, there is no intermediate 2. I wonder why. Thanks

Comment: Not strictly accurate as pyrrole nitrates 2:3 in approx 4:1 ratio

Comment: Your first set of resonance structures are wrong.